# Java String Parameters first/last parameter

Tags: java, string, char

I am just studying and can not find the solution for the following task:

That's the task:

Write a function that gets a task passed as a string parameter. We limit ourselves to searching in a text. Each task is structured as follows:

```
 <TASK> <WHAT> <TEXT>
```

You should be able to search for the first and last word or letter:

```
 <TASK> = "FIND (FIRST | LAST) (CHAR | WORD)"
```

The output should always be the place where the search starts, otherwise -1.

Examples:

```
 "FIND FIRST CHAR D This is a text" → Output: "0"
 "FIND FIRST CHAR a This is a text" → Output: "-1"
 "FIND FIRST CHAR s This is a text" → Output: "3"
 "FIND LAST CHAR t This is a text" → Output: "16"
 "FIND FIRST WORD is This is a text" → Edition: "5"
 "FIND LAST WORD is This is a text" → Output: "5"
```

Hints

- If you press Run, you will see the console output of all System.out.println

Comment: Why does the second example output -1? There's an `a` there. Why does the first example output 0? There's no `D` there.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0):

```
private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("FIND\\s+(?<pos>FIRST|LAST)\\s+(?<unit>CHAR|WORD)\\s+(?<what>\\S+)\\s+(?<text>.+)");

public static int find(String str) {
    Matcher matcher = PATTERN.matcher(str);

    if (!matcher.matches())
        return -1;

    String pos = matcher.group("pos");
    String unit = matcher.group("unit");
    String what = matcher.group("what");
    String text = matcher.group("text");
    boolean first = "FIRST".equals(pos);

    if ("CHAR".equals(unit))
        return first ? text.indexOf(what) : text.lastIndexOf(what);

    if ("WORD".equals(unit)) {
        Matcher match = Pattern.compile("\\b" + what + "\\b").matcher(text);
        int offs = -1;

        while (match.find()) {
            offs = match.start();

            if (first)
                break;
        }

        return offs;
    }

    return -1;
}
```